# Documentation for detailed outlook addin description

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, manifest, outlook-web-addins

So I see in the outlook addin library that there are some addins with fully fledged descriptions including images and carousels and all.
Where is the documentation on how to achieve this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These fields are completed when publishing your add-on into the Office Marketplace. The documentation for publishing and the required information is over there ... [Am I ready to publish?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/marketplace/checklist?source=recommendations).

Comment: So in other words I cannot have that when I side-load the addin?

Comment: No, this is part of the Office Marketplace submission. For sideloaded add-ons the manifest information `DisplayName` and `Description` will be used, but no other "reach" information can be added.